# Tailwind center div inside table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want my div (which is representing two images after the -p- **Previous Round** -p-) to be centered inside a table.

It should be in the absolute middle of the table.

I have placed it therefore inside tr and td like this:

```
    <tr>
      <td> 
       <div/>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

There's my current solution and code:
[image]

Comment: Tables are quite hard to work with, as you can't just use Flexbox or CSS Grid to change the `display` property of cells or rows. You sure you need a table for this?